# Unit tests on registers with bare metal programming

Tags: c, testing, cpu-registers, cortex-m, bare-metal

I'm trying to do a unit test by using the library "check.h" on a register containing a hexadecimal number to check if the return value is correct. The registers are for programming an STM32F030F4 ARM Cortex M0 microcontroller. However when running my test, I have a segmentation fault.

Here is the function I want to test :

```
#define GPIOA_BASE      0x48000000 
#define GPIOA_ODR       (*(volatile uint32_t *)(GPIOA_BASE + 0x14))

#define LED1            (*(volatile uint32_t *)(0))
#define OFF             0UL

uint32_t LED1_off (void) {
    GPIOA_ODR |= (OFF << LED1);
    return GPIOA_ODR ;
}
```

And here is my test :

```
START_TEST (test_LED1_off) {
    ck_assert_int_eq(0x48000014, LED1_off());
}
END_TEST
```

For information, the ck_assert_int_eq function works with a uint32_t, I have another test that works with a return value of this type.

Even though the return value is not necessarily equal to what I want to test, I get a segmentation fault when I run my tests. Here is the error :

Running suite(s): FunctionsTests
66%: Checks: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1
tests/tests.c:31:E:Core:test_LED1_off:0: (after this point) Received signal 11 (Segmentation fault)

By removing the following line: "GPIOA_ODR |= (OFF << LED1);" and by setting the return value to "1", I no longer have a segmentation fault. I have the impression that when I run my tests, my computer understands that I am trying to access its own memory.

Is what I'm trying possible ? If so how ? If not, what kind of tests can I try ? I've been struggling with this for several hours. Thanks.

Comment: What segmentation fault on a bare-metal?? There isn't such a thing. Looks like you are compiling/running you code on your PC instead.

Comment: I have a "main" target of my makefile which creates an .elf file with the arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler, and another "tests" target which creates an executable for me by compiling the functions file that I want to test used in .elf (which lights LEDs etc) using gcc.
I do my tests independently of my .elf used by the microcontroller. It doesn't make much sense I know but it's for university work

Comment: 'Hexadecimal' usually refers to a textual representation format. What is the actual test?

Comment: You can't test mcu-specific hardware interaction on your computer (well, unless you have some simulator). You might have some hardware-agnostic functions though for general processing/calculations that you might be able to test. You could also "mock" the mcu-specific stuff inside your tests, but it is not clear what exactly it will test then.

Comment: @Norronos what was `GPIOA_ODR |= (OFF << LED1);` supposed to do, given that it reduces to `GPIOA_ODR |= 0UL`? Is it a `NOP` write?

Comment: @WeatherVane no it is `GPIOA_ODR |= (0UL << *(volatile uint32_t *)0)`  which will dereference the NULL pointer (as it is `volatile`) https://godbolt.org/z/9nofs9qjf

Comment: @WeatherVane
This function is used to put a 0 in the register in order to turn off the LED on pin PA0 of my microcontroller. I therefore shift a 0 to the corresponding bit (in line with the microcontroller datasheet).
In this case, it doesn't make much sense, but to make an LED blink, I alternate between putting a 1 and a 0.
All these functions which modify values of my registers have segmentation faults when I test them. I didn't show it because it would have been redundant with the example I gave above.

Comment: @WeatherVane The definition of LED1 is quite peculiar too. I'd expect it to be the pin number instead and `OFF` to be defined something  like `0xFFFFFFFE`. And `|=` replaced by `&=`. *update*: in fact `0xFFFFFFFE` isn't right, as it will shift in zeros. The answer is providing the correct logic.

Comment: A unit test tests a unit of software independent of anything else, including hardware. Testing two things interacting (e.g. software and hardware) is an integration test. A unit test would require some isolation layer between it and the hardware, which can be mocked to provide the activity you expect from hardware, to test how the software behaves.

Comment: @Norronas as said, that's incorrect. `|= 0` does not clear a bit, although it might clear a device register status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By removing the following line: "GPIOA_ODR |= (OFF << LED1);" and by
> setting the return value to "1", I no longer have a segmentation
> fault. I have the impression that when I run my tests, my computer
> understands that I am trying to access its own memory.

On your PC you try to modify the memory at the address `GPIOA_BASE + 0x14` (more precisely you dereference pointer assigned with `GPIOA_BASE + 0x14` converted to pointer). It is definitely not memory which belongs to you and invoke segfault.

The whole test of the STM32 registers on the PC makes no sense at all.

Also:

- `OFF << LED1` dereferences NULL pointer which UB
- `|` will not reset the bit

If you want to run it on the PC you need a real object to be referenced by the pointer

```
#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(_M_X64)
static  uint32_t GPIOA_ODR;
#else
#define GPIOA_BASE      0x48000000 
#define GPIOA_ODR       (*(volatile uint32_t *)(GPIOA_BASE + 0x14))
#endif

#define LED1            0
#define OFF             1UL


uint32_t LED1_off (void) {
    GPIOA_ODR &= ~(OFF << LED1);
    return GPIOA_ODR ;
}
```

Comment: What you did works for me, however if I compile my code with arm-none-eabi-gcc and upload it to my microcontroller, the defines will have their type "(*(volatile uint32_t *)" with their addresses ?

Comment: @Norronas yes - those `#if`s are for that

Comment: Okay thank you very much for what you did, I suspected that what I was asking wasn't too understandable